# Intuition of understanding the independence of $\overline{X}$ and $X_i - \overline{X}$

Tags: probability, statistics, independence, sampling

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ be i.i.d with $E[X_i]=\mu$, Var$(X_i)= \sigma^2$. random variables. Define the sample mean as
$\overline{X} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$.

My question is how to intuitively understand the independence of $X_1 - \overline{X}$ and $X_2 - \overline{X}$; and the independence of $\overline{X}$ and $X_i - \overline{X}$.

Here is my thoughts:

$X_1-\overline{X}$ and $X_2-\overline{X}$ are independent, because $\overline{X}$ is like a fixed value in this case (please correct me if I'm wrong).

For the second question, I've calculated the covariance of $\overline{X}$ and $X_i - \overline{X}$, which equals to 0, so they are supposed to be independent. But I'm confused about how to understand their independence intuitively. From my understanding, the change of $\overline{X}$ will change the value of
$X_i - \overline{X}$, so they are not independent.

This confuses me so much, any insight will be appreciated!

Comment: Hi there -- can you show what you've tried so far -- people are downvoting because it looks like you want us to do your thinking for you. Have you tried (1) at least? Are you familiar with calculating the covariance of linear combinations of random variables?

Comment: Hi Annika, thanks for reminding me that! I will put my thoughts in the question and state my confusion more clearly!

Comment: +1 awesome :) It's a perfectly valid question but just needs to show some more effort.

Comment: In general, zero covariance doesn't imply independence... Are the $X_i$'s Gaussian ?

Comment: $X_1-\bar X$ and $X_2-\bar X$ are not independent except in trivial cases.  For $n=2$ you have $(X_1-\bar X) = -(X_2-\bar X)$.

Comment: If $X_1,X_2$ are iid $\pm1$ with equal probability, then $X_i-\bar X = 0 \iff \bar X \in \{\pm1\}$ and $X_i-\bar X \in \{ \pm1\} \iff \bar X =0$, so in that non-Gaussian case $X_i-\bar X$ is *not* independent of $\bar X$ despite the zero covariance

Comment: They are not independent. One of the basic necessary requirements for independence of two variables $X$ and $Y$ is that $Y$ should not have a functional relation with $X$. i.e., $X$ should not appear in the functional description of $Y$. But, asymptotically, $\overline{X}$ converges to a constant(due to LLN). So asymptotically, $X_{1}-\overline{X}$ and $X_{2}-\overline{X}$ behaves just like $X_{1}-c$ and $X_{2}-c$ for some real constant $c$. So in some very very weak sense you can call them independent for large $n$ but not rigourously.

Comment: @Stratossupportsthestrike Thank you for the reply! I just noticed that the book mentioned Xi's Gaussian a few pages earlier. Are $\overline{X}$ and $Xi - \overline{X}$ independent if Xi's are Gaussian?

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @Henry thank you so much for explaining! I see why they are not independent in the non-Gaussain case. I was wondering if they would be independent if $Xi's$ are Gaussian?

Comment: @MTH - yes - see my answer

Answer (score 1):

$X_1-\bar X$ and $X_2-\bar X$ are not independent except in trivial cases. For $n=2$ you have $(X_1-\bar X)=−(X_2-\bar X)$.

If $X_1,X_2$ are iid $\pm1$ with equal probability, then $X_i-\bar X=0\iff \bar X \in \{\pm1\}$ and $X_i-\bar X\in \{\pm1\}\iff \bar X=0 $, so in that non-Gaussian case $X_i-\bar X$ is not independent of $\bar X$ despite the zero covariance.

If the $X_i$ are iid Gaussian then $(X_i-\bar X,\bar X)$ is bivariate Gaussian and there is zero covariance between them, so $X_i-\bar X$ and $\bar X$ are independent.